# Jenkins service no longer starting after system update

Tags: .net, windows, jenkins, badimageformatexception

I'm getting a BadImageFormatException after our servers received a Windows Update.
Googling only hints at .NET mismatches but I can't find any problems there.
Jenkins Version is 2.263.1

Edit: Removing < supportedRuntime version="v2.x" /> from jenkins.exe.config seems to have done the trick although version="v4.0" was also in there. I leave this open in case someone has an explanation.

Comment: Starting with version 2.248, Jenkins stopped supporting .NET Framework 2.0 for launching Jenkins server and agents as a Windows service. .NET Framework 4.0 or above is now required. Check which version of .NET is available on your server.
Also go through the upgrade guidelines [here](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/07/23/windows-support-updates/#use-cases-affected-by-net-framework-2-0-support-removal)

Comment: I had version 2.263.1 running previously without issue and .NET Framework 4.0 seems to be installed on the machine. Do I need to set the version of .NET Framework to be used manually somewhere?

Comment: I didn't make any manual changes related to .NET when I updated my windows servers and Jenkins instances. Not sure why it's causing mismatch issue at your end. 

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded from Jenkins ver. 2.222.4 to Jenkins 2.303.2 from within the web UI. New versions came up, but the service would not come up again, failing with error mentioned above.

Jenkins.exe.config was last modified 2016, which let me conclude this is a stray file from a previous version.

Remove the stray jenkins.exe.config and you're all set.